# Fetch new rows - Azure Mobile Services

Tags: c#, azure, azure-mobile-services

I want my `MobileServiceIncrementalLoadingCollection<Video, Video> Videos;` (which is bound to a ListView) to be updated every 5 seconds with the new rows from my Azure Database, if any.

**Page Load**

```
Videos = VideoTable.ThenByDescending(x => x.DateTime).ToIncrementalLoadingCollection();
```

At that phase the `Videos` collection has the first items loaded (as it's an incremental loading collection), and visible in the `ListView`.

After that, every 5 seconds I am executing the following code (which is not working/adding the new rows in the collection)

```
var tempVideos = VideoTable.ThenByDescending(x => x.DateTime).ToIncrementalLoadingCollection();
var newVideos = tempVideos.Where(x => !Videos.Contains(x, new VideoComparer()));            
foreach (Video v in newVideos)
{
    Videos.Insert(0, v);

}
```

I don't want to use `Videos = tempVideos` because the whole `ListView` is updating and `AddDeleteThemeTransition` is shown for every item every 5 seconds which is really annoying and ugly.

So my question is,

How can I add the **newly added table rows** in a `MobileServiceIncrementalLoadingCollection` after the creation of the collection without recreating the collection?

PS. I am using .NET Backend if that matters.

Comment: doesn't this line `Videos.Insert(0,v);` add every new video to index 0 rather than the end of the collection?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. I want the new videos to be added at the start as the Video collection is in a descending order by DateTime.

Comment: Ah I see. Cant you call `Videos.LoadMoreItemsAsync()` every 5 seconds if `HasMoreItems` is true? Might have to test this as thought `MobileServiceIncrementalLoadingCollection` did this automatically

Comment: If the LoadMoreItemsAsync is called every 5 seconds the loaded items will be visible in the list. That's not the right use of Incremental loading collection unfortunately.

Comment: Also, I just want to update the collection with the new items which added to the database after the `Videos = VideoTable.ThenByDescending(x => x.DateTime).ToIncrementalLoadingCollection();` in the PageLoad

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want

1) to add new items to your collection, but only if they did not exist in the database in the initial call.
2) view a sorted collection

In answer:

1) This is not really the point of ToIncrementalLoadingCollection(), which is more suited to pagination or load on scroll type action. For this the control will automatically call LoadMoreItemsAsync() when required.

It sounds like you want to load all records and then update the collection with new ones. You will need to implement a query that can identify the new ones in your database and just add them to your collection.

2) As, I assume, you are using an ObservableCollection with ISupportIncrementalLoading then the trick is to sort and filter the view rather than the collection.
This means you are not that concerned about the order in which items are added to the ObservableCollection.
On your view you should implement a CollectionViewSource resource bound to your ObservableCollection in the XAML.

Comment: 1) I want to use load on scroll that's why I am using `ToIncrementalLoadingCollection`. I just want new records to be shown at the start of the binded `ListView`. Yes this is what I am trying to do. 2) Thanks for the this suggestion though. It helped me.

Comment: Did you use CollectionViewSource to get the UI sort order?